# proof problem of Period 3 point of a function

Tags: calculus, recursion

Let $f(x) = 1/(1-x)$. Show that if x ≠ 0,1, then $x$ is a period 3 point.

---

What I did was I took the 3rd iterate $f^3(x) = f(f(f(x)=x$, ie I took 
$ -\frac{1-\frac{1}{1-x}}{\frac{1}{1-x}}$ and when simplified you get $x$.

Graphically it creates a closed-loop as long as it is within (0,1). but how can I prove that $x$ is period 3 point. Is it possible to solve this algebraically or do I need to plug in numbers ?

Comment: Didn't you just do it by simplifying to $x$?

Comment: yes. I thought I didn't finish my problem. I think what I should have added in my problem was how do you find a specific cycle.  If I am trying to find 2-cycle, you do the 2nd iterate, and for this case if I take the 3rd iterate, it means i am trying to find period 3 (3-cycle) and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown that $f^3(x)=x$ for $x\ne0,1$. Therefore the function either has period $1$ or period $3$.

If it had period $1$ then $x=\frac{1}{1-x}$ which has no real solutions and therefore it has period $3$.

Comment: why not period 2?

Comment: Basically because $2$ does not divide $3$.

Comment: What do you mean by does not divide? Is there a good reference or site on periods, cycles?

Comment: You have proved that $x$ goes to $x$ after $3$ steps. If it also goes to $x$ after $2$ steps then $x$ goes to $x$ after $1$ step.